# Change the column name index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df, and when I run df.columns, I get the result in the screenshot I am attaching. I do not understand what is the result in red referring to. Furthermore, I would like to have no "name".

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
ri_2 = ri_2.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified picture of what is *df.columns* is "it is a **list** of column names".

But it is only a simplified view. Actually it is an **Index**, something like
a pandasonic *Series*, so it can have a **name** (as each *Series*).

One of possible options is to set it to *None*:

```
df.columns.name = None
```